# How to activate a FeatureLayer operation from a button using dojo/on function?

Tags: feature-layer, dojo, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

this is the setup of the FeatureLayer:

```
 on(MallaFeatureLayer.getFeatureLayer(), "before-apply-edits", lang.hitch(this, this.asignarUnidadLecturaMalla));
```

how could I link it to a button?

Answer (score 1):

To link an action with a button your need to add your button to your html page

```
<button id="select" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Sélectionner une zone</button>
```

After go to your map.js :

```
var selectionTool = dijit.byId("select");
    selectionTool.on("click",startSelect);
```

you declare your button with dijit.byid and after active the event on click to go to a function who provide your action/ call to a module :

```
function startSelect(){
        select.activate(Draw.POLYGON);
    };
```

hope i anser to your question if not give us precisions.